# syntactic difference for routing paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In a rails routes file, specifying

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, :constraints => {:subdomain => "api"}   do
```

will generate an operational URL at `api.domain.tld/api/[...]`

To remove the duplication, path can be specified.  However I have seen both `:path => "",`  and `:path => "/",`  suggested.

What practical difference is there between the two?

Comment: can you share your routes.rb code snippet? why don`t you make use of **rake routes** see what routes are getting generated.

Comment: updated.  But the question is what difference is generated by the two different syntassi

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `:path => ""`  and `:path => "/"`

For example with **routes.rb**(without forward slash in path) using `rake routes`

```
namespace(:api_namespace, :path=>"v1", :constraints => {:subdomain => "api_subdomain"}) do
  resources :todos
end
```

The routes generated are

```
  api_namespace_todos GET    /v1/todos(.:format)          api_namespace/todos#index {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
                        POST   /v1/todos(.:format)          api_namespace/todos#create {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
 new_api_namespace_todo GET    /v1/todos/new(.:format)      api_namespace/todos#new {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
edit_api_namespace_todo GET    /v1/todos/:id/edit(.:format) api_namespace/todos#edit {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
     api_namespace_todo GET    /v1/todos/:id(.:format)      api_namespace/todos#show {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
                        PUT    /v1/todos/:id(.:format)      api_namespace/todos#update {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
                        DELETE /v1/todos/:id(.:format)      api_namespace/todos#destroy {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
```

and with routes.rb(with forward slash in path)

```
namespace(:api_namespace, :path=>"/v1", :constraints => {:subdomain => "api_subdomain"}) do
  resources :todos
end
```

or

```
namespace(:api_namespace, :path=>"v1/", :constraints => {:subdomain => "api_subdomain"}) do
      resources :todos
end
```

routes generated with above code are

```
api_namespace_todos GET    /v1/todos(.:format)          api_namespace/todos#index {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
                        POST   /v1/todos(.:format)          api_namespace/todos#create {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
 new_api_namespace_todo GET    /v1/todos/new(.:format)      api_namespace/todos#new {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
edit_api_namespace_todo GET    /v1/todos/:id/edit(.:format) api_namespace/todos#edit {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
     api_namespace_todo GET    /v1/todos/:id(.:format)      api_namespace/todos#show {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
                        PUT    /v1/todos/:id(.:format)      api_namespace/todos#update {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
                        DELETE /v1/todos/:id(.:format)      api_namespace/todos#destroy {:subdomain=>"api_subdomain"}
```

The routes generated in both cases with **forward slash(i.e. /)** and **without forward slash** are exactly **same**.

Its rails which is handling the proper placing of forward slashes in URLS and allowing developers more flexibility in syntax. So practically it does not matter whether you put forward slash or not in path.